# Standalone html page with jquery to open .csv file in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, csvtotable

I am trying to open a stand alone html page in chrome browser.

This html page contains jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery.csvToTable.js to open csv file and display table in browser page.

When i try to open in Chrome browser, getting below error,

> jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130 Failed to load file:///C:/test/sample.csv:
>   *Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.*

In addition to the above, same is opening fine in Edge browser.

Comment: Investigate [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to load the page,when i launch the chrome browser by passing --allow-file-access-from-files

like this - chrome --allow-file-access-from-files file:///C:/test/index.html

But is there any other way to open the local file in chrome browser?